Sentry behavior inside a webcomponent bundle
I have a host application (ie. https://host.io) that declares a webcomponent bundle inside its HTML, that is being hosted by a microfrontend (ie. https://microfrontend.io/base/url/microfrontend-1.umd.js) I'm trying to capture errors inside the webcomponent bundle and send those errors to our Sentry.
I haven't yet tried these docs from Sentry and would love to try it out but first we wanted to see if there's a simple way to capture errors from the webcomponent bundle rather than implementing what's in the sentry docs.
I have these vite.config.ts
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig, PluginOption } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { viteVueCESubStyle } from '@unplugin-vue-ce/sub-style';
import { sentryVitePlugin } from "@sentry/vite-plugin";
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      customElement: true,
    }),
    viteVueCESubStyle() as PluginOption,
    sentryVitePlugin({
      org: "john-doe-company",
      project: "microfrontend-1",
      authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
      telemetry: false,
      release: {
        name: pkg.version,
      },
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: './webComponentsDefinition/StaticPages.ts',
      name: 'microfrontend-1',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'microfrontend-1',
    },
    outDir: './public',
    emptyOutDir: false,
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    },
  },
});

nuxt.config.ts
import pkg from "./package.json";
import { sentryVitePlugin } from "@sentry/vite-plugin";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  app: {
    baseURL: '/base/url',
    rootId: '__microFrontEndRoot',
  },
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  typescript: {
    strict: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3501,
  },
  routeRules: {
    '/microfrontend-1.umd.js': {
      'headers': {
        'Cache-Control': 'public, no-cache'
      }
    },
    '/microfrontend-1.mjs': {
      'headers': {
        'Cache-Control': 'public, no-cache'
      }
    }
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      internalUrl: '',
      sentry: {
        dsn: '',
      },
      environment: "development",
      appVersion: pkg.version,
    }, 
  },
  sourcemap: true,
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      // Setup sentry error reporting with source maps
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" 
        ? null 
        : sentryVitePlugin({
          org: "john-doe-company",
          project: "microfrontend-1",
          authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
          telemetry: false,
          release: {
            name: pkg.version,
          },
        }),
    ],
  },
});

StaticPages.ts
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue';
import StaticPage from '~/components/StaticPage/StaticPage.vue';
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/vue";

// explicitly declare it here
// I'm assuming that it will be included when I build the webcomponent bundle
// it is included but every error happened inside the webcomponent bundle 
// is not reported to SENTRY
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: "MICROFRONTEND_DSN",
    release: "1.0.0",
    environment: "development",
  });


  const MicroFrontendOneWebComponent = defineCustomElement(StaticPage);

  const isWebComponentDefined = customElements.get('microfrontend-1');

  if (!isWebComponentDefined) {
    customElements.define('microfrontend-1', MicroFrontendOneWebComponent);
  }

  Sentry.captureException(new Error("oh no!"));

StaticPage.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
  ...
  await nextTick();
  throw new Error('client error')

  emit('initialized');
});
</script>

<template>
  ...
</template>

Host application HTML sample declaring the webcomponent bundle ie. host.io
...
<script src="/base/url/microfrontend-1.umd.js" language="javascript"></script>
...

EXPECTATIONS:

In the StaticPage.vue file - the error client error should be propagated into Sentry, same expectatiob goes with Oh no!. Its origin should be microfrontend-1.umd.js when displayed in Sentry

WHAT'S HAPPENING:

It doesn't capture the error at all

OBJECTIVE:
How to capture errors inside the webcomponent bundle?

Can you give a try to that one: https://www.lichter.io/articles/nuxt3-sentry-recipe/

I have a glanced on this. Sure, will prolly update this question if this solve my question.
